# Execution time for a method listening from two events at one point of time c#

Tags: c#

I have two events which are firing at the same time and calling the same method Method1(). So at one point in time,

that method will be executed two times. And inside that method, I have another method Method2() for which I have to find the execution time.

Right now I have created 2 stopwatches one when method fired from event1 and other for event2 so that they will not block each other and I can also differentiate the execution time of method2 when method1 fired from event1 or event2 and will get the accurate results.

```
     public void Method1()
     {
          if(event1)
          {
               Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
               timer1.Start();
               Method2();
               timer1.Stop();
               Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed from event1: 
               {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
          }
          else
          {
                Stopwatch timer2 = new Stopwatch();
                timer2.Start();
                Method2();
                timer2.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed from event2: 
                {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
          }
     }
```

Any help so that I can create a common and generic stopwatch implementation that can run the event if one method is executing at some time from different sources and not have to create 2 stopwatches?

Comment: You could implement it inside the `Method2` itself so that you don't need to worry about where the call came from. Or write another method that takes an `Action` (or `Func`), which times the execution of the argument and returns a `TimeSpan` result.

Comment: You could pass an `System.Action`.

Comment: @Rufus:But for method2 also execution will be at the same time since from both events I am calling same method that is method2.

Comment: I don't understand your comment - the invocations of the method will each have their own local variables to track the timing...

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an [`System.Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.8) as a parameter and a name to apply to the log text.

```
public void ExecuteAndMeasureExecutionTime(System.Action methodToExecute, string logName = null)
{
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer1.Start();
    methodToExecute();
    timer1.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed from {0}: {1:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", logName ?? "event", stopwatch.Elapsed);
}
```

Calling code:

```
ExecuteAndMeasureExecutionTime(Method1, "Method1");
ExecuteAndMeasureExecutionTime(() => Method2(), "Method2");
```

Comment: But for the events I am calling method2 therefore  method2 will also be executed at same time one called for event1 and the other event2. And therefore at the same time execution can be there at the method you created for stopwatch.

Comment: @JacobHigs - That does not matter, everything executing in that method is locally scoped.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper method that takes in an `Action` to execute, and which returns a `TimeSpan` that represents the amount of time it took to execute the action:

```
public static TimeSpan TimeMethod(Action method)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    method.Invoke();
    sw.Stop();
    return sw.Elapsed;
}
```

Then you might call it like:

```
public void Method1()
{
    TimeSpan result = TimeMethod(Method2);
    string thisEvent = event1 ? "event1" : "event2";
    Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed from {thisEvent}: {result.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss")}");
}
```